# Can I check a certain inbound port is opening in ec2 by ssh?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

So all I have is `.pem` file, I cannot log in to the AWS to check a certain port's situation. Let's say if I want to check that the Http port (80 port) is open or not. How can I check it without log into the AWS console? I have read several articles. What they provide is tutorials telling you how to check it by logging into the AWS console, which is not what I can do.  Is there a command to do so or any test I can try?

So far I build a Nginx server and let it listen on 80 port. When I `curl localhost`, it works great. But when I try to use the IP to access it from outside, it does not work. From this, I am not pretty sure that the problem is from Nginx or the port 80 does not open. Thus, I need a more specific way to ensure that port 80 is working or not. Thank you all!

Comment: May be your nginx server is not listening for connections from outside and accepts connections from localhost only. Can you `ssh` into your machine and do `netstat -plan | grep nginx` and see if it is listening on `0.0.0.0:80` or `127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5813/nginx -g daemo

Comment: unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     31589    5813/nginx -g daemo

Comment: @helloV Thank you for your help! This is what I saw by using the command you provided.

Comment: It does listen for connections from outside the host. Asking the obvious: Is the security group open for inbound traffic from everywhere? Is your instance in the public subnet of your VPC and has a public IP or elastic IP attached?

Comment: In fact, I am not sure if the security group is oppend for inbound traffic. I might need to ask my professor. Just want to check that this is not what I can handle before seeking help from him.

Comment: From what you say, I might need to ask my professor. Thank you for your help. This is really helpful!

Comment: @helloV So.... the security group is not open for any inbound traffic. Just got this from my professor lol. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use telnet:

```
telnet <ip or dns name> 80
```

If its open you should get a message like:

```
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip or dns name>.
```